# Import into csv in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv, import

I have for example csv with a lot of columns and have my DB. I need to import all data from 1 column named `oldfile` to my database in column `symbol`. How to make it with sql query?

Comment: did you try solving this yourself first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) to import from CSV to MySQL databse table. Example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE my_table;
```

Comment: and how can i highlight concrete columns?

Comment: @AlexUlianov, go through the linked documentation page. That will help you.